# Is there video from the Falcon second stage of the Dragon solar panels deploying?

Tags: spacex, dragon, payload-deployment, video

We get video from the second stage of the Dragon leaving the second stage.
And we get video from the Dragon of its solar panels deploying.
But a cool view would be of the Dragon's solar panels deploying from the second stage.
I think it is still in range, so why don't we get to see the video ?

Comment: I doubt second stage's orientation is maintained to see the depoyment. Most probavly the stage starts oxygen dumping and rotates at this moment